# web3 calls Solidity contract function with extra parameter?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle, consensys-truffle

In the http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/pet-shop example, there is the following contract, and the function `adopt(uint petId)` has only one parameter.

```
contract Adoption {
    address[16] public adopters;

    function adopt(uint petId) public returns (uint) {
        require(petId >= 0 && petId <= 15);
        adopters[petId] = msg.sender;
        return petId;
    }

    function getAdopters() public returns (address[16]) {
        return adopters;
    }
}
```

However, in the javascript code `app.js`, the `handleAdopt` function call the contract function using the following code.

```
  App.contracts.Adoption.deployed().then(function(instance) {
    adoptionInstance = instance;
    return adoptionInstance.adopt(petId, {from: account});
  })
```

The function is called with the extra object `{from: account}`. Why? And is this parameter discarded in the solidity code?

BTW, there is an undefined global variable `web3`? Is the value be assigned by the MetaMask extension?

Comment: Refer to the answer I posted regarding the transaction object. The `web3` object is injected by MetaMask if you have the plugin installed. Otherwise, you can instantiate your own web3 object passing in a web3 provider. For example, to use an HttpProvider: const web3 = new Web3();

  web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider(providerUrl));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the `transactionObject` which describes general information about all transaction calls (gas limit, price, amount of ether to send, etc.). The JS code you posted is using the web3 library. That's not the direct call to the contract API. The web3 library converts it to an RPC. The `transactionObject` comes after all of the contract parameters. There is another parameter that comes after which is the callback with the results of the contract call (see [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods)).

These are all of the options for the `transactionobject` described from the [docs](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction):

> - from: String - The address for the sending account. Uses the web3.eth.defaultAccount property, if not specified.
> - to: String - (optional) The destination address of the message, left undefined for a contract-creation transaction.
> - value: Number|String|BigNumber - (optional) The value transferred for the transaction in Wei, also the endowment if it's a contract-creation transaction.
> - gas: Number|String|BigNumber - (optional, default: To-Be-Determined) The amount of gas to use for the transaction (unused gas is refunded).
> - gasPrice: Number|String|BigNumber - (optional, default: To-Be-Determined) The price of gas for this transaction in wei, defaults to the mean network gas price.
> - data: String - (optional) Either a byte string containing the associated data of the message, or in the case of a contract-creation transaction, the initialisation code.
> - nonce: Number - (optional) Integer of a nonce. This allows to overwrite your own pending transactions that use the same nonce.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a little bit surprised that the call allows the address for sending account to be overridden to some values. So I can call the contract on behalf of others? Could it be a security concern?

Comment: Accounts need to be unlocked to initiate transactions.